# Windows 7 takes forever to shut down

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

So. This problem occured on both mine, and my friend's PC. Our PCs differ pretty much (specs at bottom). Basically, it takes forever ... literally, OR really long to restart or shutdown.

I have enabled the "VerboseStatus" registry key, to see what's happening. The only thing I discovered by doing this, is Windows is stopping at: "Notifying services ..." OR at "Shutting down"; but it doesn't happen always.

What I tried:
- Checking drivers. Bios. Updated my Bios to the latest stable. Audio driver removed, installed the Gigabyte version. Same with INF update, etc. Removed nVidia beta driver too, installed the stable 280.xx one.
- Checked services, network adapters. Nothing suspicious. Removed Avast!, nothing.

I suspect some software issue, but I have no idea what might be the cause.
The [installed updates](http://pastebin.com/VMhZqeKr).

**If you need any further information, please comment, and I'll add the requested stuff ASAP.**

My PC:
OS: Windows 7 x64 Professional SP1 ENG
CPU: Intel Core i7 950 @ 3.06ghz
RAM: 12gb DDR3 1600mhz XMP1
VGA: Zotac nVidia GTX260^2 AMP2
PSU: Corsair Enthusiast series 750W v2

Friend's PC:
OS: Windows 7 x64 Professional SP1 ENG
CPU: AMD Phenom X6 1090T
RAM: 8gb DDR3 1066mhz
VGA: Sapphire ATI Radeon 4850
PSU: Chieftec 500W

Comment: do you both happen to have the same HDDs?

Comment: Start troubleshooting hardware?

Comment: are you able to revert back before this issue happened? that way you can determine if it's related to a windows update?

Comment: @NickJosevski - I have 2WD Black Caviar drives in Raid0, using the Marvel controller on my motherboard. He uses an Intel X25-M 80gb SSD.

Comment: No, it wasn't an update related problem.

Comment: I was able to find the culprit, but I don't know what to do about it. It is the Microsoft Bits Client and it is messing up bad on shutdown, even to the point of stopping for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a rogue service or driver. If you look in the Event Viewer then check under Application logs/ Microsoft WIndows/ Diag-Performance, Windows will list drivers and the time it takes for them to shut down.  Try looking there.

**edit**

A more advanced and thorough tool is the xbootmgr from the Xperf tools.  You can download it from Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801

This is the xbootmgr quick start guide.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff190973(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Where can I find this Driver list / time ? Can't find it in Performance monitor / Event viewer.

Comment: I listed where the log is.